# Frequent disconnect on NIC @ Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, networking

It was late here and I'm having problem thinking of a solution for this.
There's this Windows Server 2012 R2 in our environment, and it has 3 NIC on it.

I have observed that this NIC-1 is giving a trouble, it will lose connectivity to the gateway in every 30 minutes interval.

NIC-1 IP: 10.1.0.101
Default Gateway: 10.1.0.1
Mask: 255.255.255.0

At least, there is another 2-3 servers (same OS) behave like this now. They will periodically 'Request time out' on NIC-1 interface, but not on the other 2 interfaces.

Where should I begin to look for faults and fix it?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I was hoping that was not a faulty network card. It can't be right to happen for a number of servers/HWs at the same time?

Comment: You need to give us more details on the nature of the problem? What exactly do you mean that they lose connectivity with the gateway? How do they lose connectivity? What troubleshooting have you done? What are the exact symptoms of the problem?

Comment: Have you ever carried out any form of network troubleshooting before?

Comment: @BlueCompute I've done a few on client machine, but not on server. Can you show me the proper troubleshooting for this case?

Answer (score 0):

@joeqwerty

Sorry for the lack of details.

I was sitting idle on RDP session to that server (Server1).
And I noticed it will automatically disconnect me in every 30mins sharp.

I did ping from Server2 and Server3 to the IP address on NIC-1 on that problematic Server1 continuously, and noticed there's ping timeout for every 30mins interval.

Any suggestions is welcomed.